# Using Eureka Pod with iPad 4th Gen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, cocoapods

I have written an app that allows me to read and write to and from a Firebase database. The data that is found is displayed back to the user in a tableview. I have used Eureka to build the tableview. This has been working fine when tested on my own device (iPhone 7 iOS 11.2.5). I have used this device, along with the Xcode simulator whilst developing. 
I have now been asked to trial the application in my workplace and have been given iPads (4th Generation iOS 10.3.3) to do this on.

On attempting to test the app on the iPad, I get the error "No such module 'Eureka'".
And also:
"Target 'Pods-SMART.Assets' of project 'Pods' was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'Pods_SMART_Assets.framework' because its architectures 'arm64' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7'"

I have tried dropping the deployment target from 11.2 to 10.3 but still get the same message. I am thinking maybe I need an earlier version of Eureka?

Any advice would be massively appreciated as I am now contemplating rewriting the app with a custom tableview...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after a lot of messing about I've managed to sort it:

- Firstly I changed the iOS Deployment Target of my project to 10.3.
- Then I opened the 'Pods' project and also changed the iOS Deployment Target to 10.3.
- Still in the 'Pods' project, I added 'armv7' to the 'Valid Architectures' list.
- Finally, in the 'Targets' section for 'Pods-SMART.Assets' I also added 'armv7' to the 'Valid Architectures' list.

Sorted!

Hope this helps someone else one day!